# Bootstrap delegated pop over content callback triggered twice

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, events, delegates

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 and I'm registering a popover to open whenever a td with a selector is hovered over. However I have noticed within the console that the content callback is being trigger twice. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
$('#table-data').popover({
    selector: '.td-popover',
    trigger : 'hover',
    content : function () {
        console.log(this, arguments)
        return 'hello';
    }
});

<table id="table-data">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-popover"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-popover"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use a different class for one of them with a different message. You have td-popover listed in two areas.

Comment: In my real scenario I have more than 2 td with that class and it is still only triggered twice.

Comment: Can you provide an example online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is correct, this issue comes from bootstrap itself, they say that it is an intentional behavior and not a bug. see this github issue for more details https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12563

FYI they didn't change this behavior in Bootstrap 3.2 (which is the current stable release), but I think that they plan to do it in the next one (3.2.1)

Comment: Yeah they seem uninterested in fixing it, and its not documented as far as I can discover. Poor form, twitter.